# How do you write a good product description?

Tags: creative-writing, technical-writing

Are there any rules or procedure to write a great product description. Any examples of good desciptions online?

Comment: What kind of product description?  An attention-grabbing web page?  A brochure to be sent out to qualified leads?  A detailed specification for a complex piece of equipment?  A social-media pitch?

Answer (score 0):

Your description will need to tell what the product is, and describe it in the best possible light.  Use vivid prose to accentuate the positive, and never mention the negative.  You are seeking to draw buyers into wanting to but the product, so you should also identify a felt need that this product will address.  Hope this helps!

Comment: He said product description, not product advertisement.

Comment: A product description could be for multiple contexts: advertising, instruction manuals, engineering, project management, safety warnings, etc. etc. The main problem here is the _very_ general requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of product, and the specific supply chain, there are even very particular standards.

If you could supply more detail as noted in the comment to the OP, it might be possible to suggest something very relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to write Google Algorithm friendly product description, you have to follow the guideline like following:

1. Length of description: 300 to 500 words

   2. Error free(good grammar)
   3. Good Keyword research
   4. Relevant Product Description etc